# Getting and setting multiple ratings in one page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have this rating system which works fine for one item per page, but I would like to change it so that multiple items can be rated.

The rendered html for each item is this - with `data-id=""` containing unique ids:

```
<div class="ratings">
  <span class="ratingAverage" data-av="0"></span>
  <span class="item" data-id="7"></span>
  <div class="bar">
    <span class="bg" style="width: 96%;"></span>
    <span class="stars">
      <span class="star full" data-vote="1">
        <span class="starimg"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="star full" data-vote="2">
          <span class="starimg"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="star full" data-vote="3">
          <span class="starimg"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="star full" data-vote="4">
          <span class="starimg"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="star" data-vote="5">
          <span class="starimg"></span>
      </span>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="votes"><span>12 votes</span></div>
</div>
```

js:

```
// Rating
  var average = $('.ratingAverage').attr('data-av');
  function getAvg(average) {
    average = (Number(average) * 20);
    $('.bg').css('width', 0);
    $('.bar .bg').animate({
      width: average + '%'
    }, 500);
  }

  getAvg(average);

  $('.star').on('mouseover', function() {
    var indexAtual = $('.star').index(this);
    for (var i = 0; i <= indexAtual; i++) {
      $('.star:eq(' + i + ')').addClass('full');
    }
  });

  $('.star').on('mouseout', function() {
    $('.star').removeClass('full');
  });

  $('.star').on('click', function() {
    var itemId = $('.item').attr('data-id');
    var vote = $(this).attr('data-vote');
    $.post('vote.php', {
      vote: 'yes',
      item: itemId,
      point: vote
    }, function(data, status) {
      getAvg(data.average);
      var suffix = (data.votes == 1)
        ? "vote"
        : "votes";
      $('.votes span').html(data.votes + " " + suffix);
    }, 'jSON');
  });
```

But this .js sets the same voting for all items. How can I collect `average` for each item and run `getAvg(average)` on each item?

vote.php:

```
<?php
    // Connect to db here.
    if(isset($_POST['vote'])){

        $id = (int)$_POST['item'];
        $points = (int)$_POST['point'];
        $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT votes, rating FROM ". $DBtable ." WHERE `id` = ?");
        $query->execute(array($id));

        while($row = $query->fetchObject()){
            $pointsUpdate = ($row->rating+$points);
            $voteUpdate = ($row->votes+1);

            $updateQuery = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE ". $DBtable ." SET `votes` = ?, `rating` = ? WHERE `id` = ?");
            if($updateQuery->execute(array($voteUpdate, $pointsUpdate, $id))){
                $avg = round(($pointsUpdate/$voteUpdate),1);
                die(json_encode(array('average' => $avg, 'votes' => $voteUpdate)));
            } else {
                echo "Could not update votes";
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

I hope this code is enough to demonstrate the issue.
Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $('.ratingAverage').each(function(){
    var average = $(this).attr('data-av');
    average = (Number(average) * 20);
    $(this).next('.bg').css('width', 0);
    $(this).next('.bar .bg').animate({
      width: average + '%'
    }, 500);
  });


$('.star').on('click', function() {
    var rating = $(this).closest(".ratings");
    var itemId = rating.find('.item').attr('data-id');
    var vote = $(this).attr('data-vote');
    $.post('vote.php', {
      vote: 'yes',
      item: itemId,
      point: vote
    }, function(data, status) {
       var average = (Number(data.average) * 20);
       rating.find('.bg').css('width', 0);
       rating.find('.bar .bg').animate({
          width: average + '%'
       }, 500);
      var suffix = (data.votes == 1)
        ? "vote"
        : "votes";
      $('.votes span').html(data.votes + " " + suffix);
    }, 'jSON');
  });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But then what do I do inside the `$.post()` where the `getAvg(data.average)` function is called?

Comment: Sorry, I had not seen this call